# after each command, if success: show a custom message, if error: show error, and send to file

Tags: linux, bash

A bash script executes several commands.
After each command, how to:

- if success: show a custom message in the console and append it to a log file
- if error: show the error message in the console, append error message to the log file and resume the entire script

Here is where I am:

```
log_file="log.txt"
output() {
  echo $@
  echo $@ 2>&1 >> $log_file;
  if [ $@ -eq 0 ]
  then
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

and then after each command:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then 
  output "Custom message"
else
  output $?
fi
```

Which makes lots of repetitions…

Comment: if you show (what you tried): you might get an answer; if you don't: you probably won't.

Comment: @isedev Sure. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a "run" function to limit repetition:

```
run()
{
  message="$1"
  shift
  eval "$*"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    output "$message"
  else
    output $?
  fi
 }
```

And simply prefix every command with:

```
 run "message" "command"
```

The command only needs to be quoted if it contains shell meta-expressions.

Comment: cool! and how to pass a specific custom message message for each command?

Comment: edited accordingly... make sure to quote pass custom message as first argument to "run" and quote it.

Comment: added "eval" to enable complex quoted commands to be passed to the "run" function (e.g. "this | that && ok").

Comment: When I run it on `run "set config" sed -i '' -e "s/\(define('_DB_NAME_', \).*/\1'$db_name');/" $db_config` this makes an error on the `eval $*` line: `syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Comment: The problem you're facing is a quoting issue. I've updated the answer to be even more bulletproof, but, since you're already using both single and double quotes in your command, you need to double quote it and escape internal double quotes: `run "set config" "sed -i '' -e \"s/\(define('_DB_NAME_', \).*/\1'$db_name');/\" $db_config"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to accomplish that; after each command to be tracked, add this line:

```
rc="$?"; if [ "$rc" -eq 0 ]; then echo "Custom message" 2>&1 | tee -a /folder/log; else echo "$rc" 2>&1 | tee -a /folder/log; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will give you the exit status of your last run command.

> $?

e.g lets say you executed "ls" command , after that if you execute the following

> echo $?

you will see the exit status as 0. which means successful . An  Non-zero exit status means failure.

You can use this in some sort of if else in your shell script and based on the exit value do whatever you need to do.